# Laravel 5.3 and Vue Webpack setup

Tags: laravel, webpack, browserify, vue.js

Hello I am getting JS errors in app.js. Basically it is not liking require('./bootstrap'); and gives the error:

```
all.js:50750 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

My app.js:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * include Vue and Vue Resource. This gives a great starting point for
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "buble": "^0.13.2",
    "buble-loader": "^0.3.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-11",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "vue": "^2.0.3",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^1.2.0",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.3",
    "vue-loader": "^9.7.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-style-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  }
}
```

Example.Vue:

```
    <template>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Example Component</div>

                        <div class="panel-body">
                            I'm an example component!
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component ready.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

I also have a webpack.config.js:

```
'use strict'

const path  = require('path')

module.exports = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'resources/assets'),
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'buble',
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue',
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css'
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

bootstrap.js file

```
window._ = require('lodash');

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap-sass');

/**
 * Vue is a modern JavaScript library for building interactive web interfaces
 * using reactive data binding and reusable components. Vue's API is clean
 * and simple, leaving you to focus on building your next great project.
 */

window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-resource');

/**
 * We'll register a HTTP interceptor to attach the "CSRF" header to each of
 * the outgoing requests issued by this application. The CSRF middleware
 * included with Laravel will automatically verify the header's value.
 */

Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {
    request.headers.set('X-CSRF-TOKEN', Laravel.csrfToken);

    next();
});

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

// import Echo from "laravel-echo"

// window.Echo = new Echo({
//     broadcaster: 'pusher',
//     key: 'your-pusher-key'
// });
```

my gulpfile.js

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-webpack-official');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */
var paths = {
    'cssstyles': 'resources/assets/css/',
    'jsscripts': 'resources/assets/js/',

    'adminlte': 'vendor/bower_components/AdminLTE/',
    'bootstrap': 'vendor/bower_components/bootstrap/',
    'chartjs': 'vendor/bower_components/Chart.js/dist/',
    'fastclick': 'vendor/bower_components/fastclick/',
    'fontawesome': 'vendor/bower_components/font-awesome/',
    'jquery': 'vendor/bower_components/jquery/',
    'slimscroll': 'vendor/bower_components/slimScroll/',
    'datatables': 'vendor/bower_components/datatables.net/',
    'moment': 'vendor/bower_components/moment/',
    'bootstrapgrowl': 'vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-growl/'
}

elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;


elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss', paths.cssstyles)
        .styles([
            paths.bootstrap + 'dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            paths.fontawesome + 'css/font-awesome.css',
            paths.adminlte + 'plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css',
            paths.adminlte + 'dist/css/AdminLTE.css',
            paths.adminlte + 'dist/css/skins/skin-blue.css',
            paths.adminlte + 'plugins/select2/select2.css',
            paths.cssstyles + 'dataTables.fontAwesome.css',
            paths.cssstyles + 'app.css'
        ], 'public/css/', './')

        .scripts([
            paths.jquery + "dist/jquery.js",
            paths.moment + 'moment.js',
            paths.bootstrap + "dist/js/bootstrap.js",
            paths.datatables + "js/jquery.dataTables.js",
            paths.fastclick + "lib/fastclick.js",
            paths.adminlte + "dist/js/app.js",
            paths.adminlte + 'plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js',
            paths.adminlte + 'plugins/select2/select2.js',
            paths.adminlte + 'plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js',
            paths.slimscroll + "jquery.slimscroll.js",
            paths.chartjs + "Chart.js",
            paths.bootstrapgrowl + 'jquery.bootstrap-growl.js',
            paths.jsscripts + "app.js"
        ], 'public/js/', './')


    mix.webpack('app.js');

});
```

I have spent hours on this and the documentation on the web is not very clear as I am confused between browserify and webpack. I do want to state that I am not very front end savvy. Just want to have things in order so that can utilize Vue in future. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: What version of `npm` and `node` do you have installed?

Comment: npm 2.15.11   node v6.9.1

Comment: @Ross Wilson   I upgraded npm to 3.10.9. Same result.

Comment: No errors when you `gulp` the file?

Comment: @WebKenth No errors. :(

Comment: @craig_h I have updated my answer above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So dumb. I was not including the generated JS file. Thanks to everyone that took a stab at this.